# How to convert array in double quotes back as original array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How to convert this string into original array in Javascript?

```
var str_arr = "["myName","asldkfjs","2342","sbc@lkjsf.com","sdlkfjskldf",410]"
```

like I want to store it back as original array

```
var arr = ["myName","asldkfjs","2342","sbc@lkjsf.com","sdlkfjskldf",410];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "original" array in your first sentence?

Comment: I mean, remove double quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: Your first line is invalid JavaScript. You need to use single quotes or escape your inner double quotes.

Answer (score 4):

You have a syntax error in your str_arr.

```
var str_arr = '["myName","asldkfjs","2342","sbc@lkjsf.com","sdlkfjskldf",410]';
var arr = JSON.parse(str_arr);
```

Comment: does this work? meaning remove double quotes and replace with single?

Comment: Yes, double quotes and single quotes are the same in JS

Comment: It's easy to verify this in a browser console or a nodejs repl. The original post using the double quotes to start the string would cause a syntax error, due to an unexpected identifier, which would be the first m, because of the previous double quotes. So you gotta be careful how you initialize a string that has quotes in them.

Answer (score 3):

You could try parsing it as JSON, because an array is valid JSON (assuming it uses double quotes for the strings).

```
arr = JSON.parse(str_arr);
```

Also, as @manonthemat mentioned, you need to either use single quotes to wrap the string literal where you declare str_arr (since it contains double quotes) or you need to escape the double quotes to avoid a syntax error.